# Reaction of Iron with Concentrated and dilute hydrochloric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, metallurgy

Does Iron react differently with dilute and concentrated hydrochloric acid?
A. I know that with dilute hydrochloric acid Iron (II) chloride is formed.
B. I read on the internet that with concentrated hydrochloric acid Iron reacts to form Iron (III) Chloride.
Could someone tell me:
1. Is FeCl3 formed as a product of reaction between HCl (conc.) and iron?
2. If yes, then what is the complete chemical reaction?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Formation of ferrous chloride or ferric chloride](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41095/7951)

Answer (score 4):

No, $\ce{FeCl3}$ is not formed upon reaction with Conc. $\ce{HCl}$. Both dilute and concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ give $\ce{FeCl2}$ as product.

$$\ce{Fe + 2HCl_{dil} -> Fe^2+ +  2Cl^- + H2 ^}$$
$$\ce{Fe + 2HCl_{conc} -> Fe^2+ +  2Cl^- + H2 ^}$$

Source: Vogel's Qualitative Inorganic Analysis

Comment: You want to add this statement to your answer:-"Liberation of hydrogen prevents the formation of ferric chloride".

Comment: @NilayGhosh  why does hydrogen oppose the reaction? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DatBoi Hydrogen prevents oxidation from $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$. Refer to the [previous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41095/formation-of-ferrous-chloride-or-ferric-chloride?noredirect=1&lq=1): "Acids can oxidize iron since the redox potentials E for pH=0 show that $\ce{H+}$ can oxidize iron to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ but [non-oxidizing acids (in this case HCl)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51068/clear-definition-of-a-non-oxidizing-acid) cannot further oxidize $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$." If there is presence of oxygen, it can oxidize to $\ce{Fe^3+}$.